# why type protected is failed in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have faced one issue, see this link in typescript platform https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcoF4oHICGaoB90CNs80BjNAbgChRIoBJANRSgG9KooBtAa3igEsAdrHgIAugH4AXFEEBXALb4IAJyoBfSiQA2GBEgCqCVa3ZQwK-gDcMwaDe1yICGY2Yt1VMxgAmPgMIA9nKCwAAUvCAycIgANFAkwaEy8kqqAJSmHBz8AGZQYTQQgfnAABb8CAB0Dk4IPPBiKMioaKnKKmiZbNnZ5ZU1GI7ODSBNqP3VtSORTQDUUACMVL2aHJrqQA；

I don't understand why typeof in this scene can't infer 'this.values[key]' type correctly;

Answer (score 0):

This happen because you defined `values` as empty object without keys. So error make sense: `this.values[key]` is `undefined` when you trying to access to.

All you need is add check if object property exist and set default value if not:

```
type Keys = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';
type IV = {
  [key in Keys]?: number;
}
class User {
  private values: IV = {};

  addCount(key: Keys, count: number) {
    if (typeof this.values[key] === 'number') {
      this.values[key] = (this.values[key] || 0) + 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: but "typeof this.values[key] === 'number'" is not enough to infer the real type of values? And i tried to define values as {a: 1, b: 1, c: 1}, it still can not infer the real tyepe

Answer (score -1):

I think `type Keys = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';` the first line is wrong.
here you should provide a data type not a value.